# Separar Columna SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen dia tengo el siguiente resultado en sql:

006-UD2005-0004109

quiero separarlo quedando de la siguiente manera

```
Sucursal Documento FOLIO 
006         UD2005  0004109
```

el detalle es que a veces tengo nada mas `UD2005-0004109`, no viene el `006-` quiero que igual quede:

```
sucursal Documento  Folio 
          UD2005      0004109
```

como lo puede separar de esta manera? Además, quiero que cuando se obtenga el DOCUMENTO UD2005 quede tambien separado de la siguiente manera U D 20 05 en columnas independientes

Comment: Cuáles son los nombres de las columnas? Siempre serán divididos en la misma longitud? Por qué se pierde un cero?

Comment: si es la misma longitud ya la edite error de dedo mio con lo del cero

Comment: podria ser con charindex?

Comment: CHARINDEX encuentra la posición de un caracter en una cadena. No divide cadenas.

Comment: ya pude amigo muchas gracias me sirvió mucho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otra de las opciones seria utilizando la funcion STRING_SPLIT y MAX de sql server para separar las cadena

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT  
max(case when len(value)=3 then value end) as Sucusal
,max(case when len(value)=6 then value end) as Documento
,max(case when len(value)=7 then value end) as Folio  
FROM STRING_SPLIT('UD2005-0004109' ,'-')
```

Aplicándole para varios registros se puede hacer usando un `CROSS APPLY`

Ejemplo:

```
--DROP TABLE #tablaTemporal
--Crear Tabla temporal para realizar ejemplo practico
CREATE TABLE #tablaTemporal(ID INT,Campo1 varchar(20))
insert into #tablaTemporal( ID, Campo1) values(1,'UD2005-0004109')
insert into #tablaTemporal( ID, Campo1) values(2,'006-UD2005-0004109')

--SELECT * FROM #tablaTemporal

SELECT  
ID
,max(case when len(value)=3 then value end) as Sucusal
,max(case when len(value)=6 then value end) as Documento
,max(case when len(value)=7 then value end) as Folio  
FROM #tablaTemporal CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Campo1 ,'-') GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: esta muy buena de hecho pero si tengo la consulta select referencia from tabla, referencia me da varios resultados como UD2005-0004109, como adapto tu código a esto?

Comment: @JavierSolis he actualizado la respuesta con un ejemplo para aplicarle a varios registros.

Answer (score 1):

Esto parece una buena oportunidad para utilizar la función [PARSENAME](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql). Solo hay que tener en cuenta 2 cosas:

- Cada valor debe ser de una longitud menor a 128 caracteres.
- Si hay puntos, se deben cambiar por un caracter distinto y luego regresarlos.

Dejo ejemplo de como hacerlo de forma sencilla y de forma segura.

```
SELECT *,
    PARSENAME( REPLACE( Resultado, '-', '.'), 3) AS sucursal,
    PARSENAME( REPLACE( Resultado, '-', '.'), 2) AS documento,
    PARSENAME( REPLACE( Resultado, '-', '.'), 1) AS folio
FROM (VALUES( '006-UD2005-0004109'), 
            ('UD2005-0004109'))x(Resultado)


SELECT *,
    REPLACE( PARSENAME( REPLACE( REPLACE( Resultado, '.', CHAR(7)), '-', '.'), 3), CHAR(7), '.') AS sucursal,
    REPLACE( PARSENAME( REPLACE( REPLACE( Resultado, '.', CHAR(7)), '-', '.'), 2), CHAR(7), '.') AS documento,
    REPLACE( PARSENAME( REPLACE( REPLACE( Resultado, '.', CHAR(7)), '-', '.'), 1), CHAR(7), '.') AS folio
FROM (VALUES( '006-UD2005-0004109'), 
            ( 'UD2005-0004109'), 
            ( '006-UD.2005-0004109'))x(Resultado)
```

Para dividir la columna de documento, sólo necesitas usar SUBSTRING sobre esa parte del valor. Para evitar repetir todo el cálculo, podemos usar la clausula APPLY.

```
SELECT Resultado,
    sucursal,
    SUBSTRING( documento, 1, 1),
    SUBSTRING( documento, 2, 1),
    SUBSTRING( documento, 3, 2),
    SUBSTRING( documento, 5, 2),
    folio
FROM #Prueba
CROSS APPLY (SELECT PARSENAME( REPLACE( Resultado, '-', '.'), 3) AS sucursal,
                    PARSENAME( REPLACE( Resultado, '-', '.'), 2) AS documento,
                    PARSENAME( REPLACE( Resultado, '-', '.'), 1) AS folio) d;
```

Comment: me sirvio amigo nadas como puedo separar UD2005  en U    D  20  05

Comment: Lo que está después del `FROM` en mi resupuesta es simplemente lo que genera los datos de prueba. Cada columna individual la puedes aplicar a cualquier consulta con tan solo cambiar `Resultado` por el nombre de la columna que deseas separar.

Comment: me sirvio amigo nadas como puedo separar UD2005 en U D 20 05

Comment: Eso sería ampliar la pregunta. Si la editas, puedo ampliar la respuesta.

Comment: listo ya la edite